# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working with a Java program (reading large files) on Eclipse - Windows. After running my program I get the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I see on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom that I should add the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line.

Where should I add this option? How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded?rq=1

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: you can add new arguments in eclipse: Run > Run Configuration.. > Arguments(x). Anyway I can't tell if it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

In your Tomcat `bin` folder you will find a file `Catalina.sh` which has a variable called `CATALINA_OPTS`. You need set it with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`.

Though I am not very learned in this subject, AFAIK this is a temporary solution. You make check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2864256/1172611) answer. It might help.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find the file 'Catalina.sh'? Where can I find this file?